# If array is empty how do I exclude it from json_encode? (PHP)

Tags: php, json

I'm building json sub-array structure (from CSV) using the following PHP:

```
$tracks = array();
foreach ($result['tracks'] as $trackdata) {
    $songId    = $trackdata['songId'];
    $title     = $trackdata['title'];
    $ISRC      = $trackdata['ISRC'];
    $name1     = $trackdata['artists:name[1]'];
    $name2     = $trackdata['artists:name[2]'];
    $main1     = $trackdata['artists:main[1]'];
    $main2     = $trackdata['artists:main[2]'];

    $tracks['tracks'][] = array(
        'songId' => $songId,
        'title' => $title,
        'ISRC' => $ISRC,
        'artists' => array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => $name1,
                'main' => (boolean) $main1
            ),
            1 => array(
                'name' => $name2,
                'main' => (boolean) $main2
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Currently, if the CSV contains empty values the json (correctly) displays the value as NULL.

What would I need to add to my PHP to stop a particular object from being part of the json if its value is empty / blank?

I'm specifically looking to not print **artists:name[2]** and **artists:main[2]** if a second artists doesn't exist in the CSV data.

Here is an example of the CSV code:

```
"trk-04","track 4","USAM18490006","John Smith",true,,
```

I've researched (and attempted to implement) if (empty... but I'm not sure where that would come in this code.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to avoid adding the second artist to the intermediate array that you subsequently json-encode.

```
$tracks = array();
foreach ($result['tracks'] as $trackdata) {
    $songId    = $trackdata['songId'];
    $title     = $trackdata['title'];
    $ISRC      = $trackdata['ISRC'];
    $name1     = $trackdata['artists:name[1]'];
    $name2     = $trackdata['artists:name[2]'];
    $main1     = $trackdata['artists:main[1]'];
    $main2     = $trackdata['artists:main[2]'];

    $artists = array();
    // First artist always exists
    $artists[] = array('name' => $name1, 'main' => (boolean) $main1);
    // Add second artist only if one exists with a non-null name
    if(!is_null($name2)) {
      $artists[] = array('name' => $name2, 'main' => (boolean) $main2);
    }

    $tracks['tracks'][] = array(
        'songId' => $songId,
        'title' => $title,
        'ISRC' => $ISRC,
        'artists' => $artists
    );
}
```

You can use the `empty` function instead of `is_null` if you wish.  It will consider names such as empty strings and the number 0 as not existing.  `is_null` will only catch those which are strictly === null.

Comment: This using **!empty** got me the result I was looking for. Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
if (!empty($songId))
{
    $tracks['tracks']['songId'] = $songId;
}
if (!empty($title))
{
    $tracks['tracks']['title'] = $title;
}
and so on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$artists[0] = array(
            'name' => $name1,
            'main' => (boolean) $main1
        );
if (!empty($name2)&&!empty($main2))
    $artists[1] = array(
            'name' => $name2,
            'main' => (boolean) $main2
        );
$tracks['tracks'][] = array(
    'songId' => $songId,
    'title' => $title,
    'ISRC' => $ISRC,
    'artists' => $artists
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (  ( ! isset( artists:name[2] ))
   || ( empty( artists:name[2] ))
   )  {

  unset( $tracks['tracks'][ 'artists' ][ 1 ] );

}
```

Better

```
$n = 0;
while( ! empty( $trackdata[ 'artists:name[' . $n+1 . ']' ] )) {

   $tracks['tracks'][ 'artists' ][ $n ][ 'name' ] 
       = $trackdata[ 'artists:name[' . $n+1 . ']' ];

   $tracks['tracks'][ 'artists' ][ $n ][ 'main' ] 
       = $trackdata[ 'artists:main[' . $n+1 . ']' ];

  $n++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter to filter out unset date from an array

```
 // assuming $artist is an array you want to scrub

 $artist = array_filter($artist);
 $track["artists"][] = $artist;
```